# Errror when packaging sencha touch for ios debug

Tags: java, ios, sencha-touch

I'm trying to package a sencha application for ios. But when I in the terminal do:     "sencha package build package.json" I get the following 
      : [ERR] null
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppEnvironment.(AppEnvironment.java:48)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.load(BuildEnvironment.java:193)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.loadBuildEnvironment(Sencha.java:374)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:127)

I probably screwed something up with the certficates and provisioning profiles, but, I'm not sure if this is some kind of environment error, ie sencha cmd not finding path of Java. The error seems to suggest this, but the cmd works with other commands. I can, for example, create a new app with "sencha app generate myapp ..myapp".

So, my question is really, is the error caused by some environment problem, and if so, what to do about it, or is his a problem related to some errror in my packager.json. Here's my packager.json file.

All help much appreciated!

```
{
"applicationName":"app",
"applicationId":"com.appname",
"bundleSeedId":"xxxxxxxx",
"versionString":"1.0",

"iconName":"icon.png",
"icon": {
    "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png",
    "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png",
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"
},

"inputPath":"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/",
"outputPath":"../build/",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"iOS",
"deviceType":"Universal",

"certificatePath":"../cert/mycert.p12",
"certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer:",
"certificatePassword":"",
"provisionProfile":"../cert/name.mobileprovision",
"notificationConfiguration":"",

"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
```

}

Comment: What output do you get if you run `sencha -d` with the debug switch? I encountered a similar failure mode (`[ERR] null`) caused by the presence of `.svn` metadata folders.